# Error:Could not route into another page in ionic

Tags: ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

I can't navigate to it another template 
its shows me error above

and i also tried ui-sref to  go signup templete

- Here My Starter app Structure--

I have templates of

1. Login.html
2. Signup.html
3. dash.html

**Here my index page**

```
 <body ng-app="starter">
<ion-tab title="Home" >
      <ion-nav-view name="menuContent"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab> 

 <ion-nav-bar >
  <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon ion-ios7-arrow-back">

  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>


     <ion-nav-view >  </ion-nav-view> -->

<ion-header-bar class="bar-stable">
    <h1 class="title">Login</h1>
</ion-header-bar>
<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

*and my app.js is*

```
     .state('login', {
      url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
       controller: 'LoginCtrl'
  })
.state('Fourm' ,{
    url : '/SignUp',
   templateUrl: 'templates/SignUp.html',
  controller :'SignCtrl'
  })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

**and my Controller.js**

```
 .controller('LoginCtrl', function($scope, LoginService, $ionicPopup, $state) {
    $scope.data = {};

    $scope.Login = (function() {
        LoginService.loginUser($scope.data.username, $scope.data.password).success(function(data) {
          //var Popup = $ionicPopup.alert({title : 'Login success'})
          alert("Welcome User")
          $state.go('tab');

        }).error(function(data) {
            var alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                title: 'Login failed!',
                template: 'Please check your credentials!'
            });
        });
    })

)

.controller('SignCtrl' ,  function($scope, $ionicPopup, $state) {
     console.log("in cotrl")
        $scope.SignUp = (function() 
        {

           alert("user")


           $state.go('Fourm');
        });
      })
```

**and my LoginTemplate**

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
  <ion-content class="padding">
      <div class="list list-inset" >
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
          </label>
          <label class="item item-input">
              <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
          </label>
      </div>
      <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="Login()">Login</button>

      <<button class="button button-block button-assertive" ng-click="SignUp()" >SignUp</button>


  </ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Not a good way to put **ion-tab** in index.html unless you want tab in all page in your app.

2) `ion-tab` define single tab which should be in **ion-tabs** container.

3) In angular ui router for tab container we have to define **route with abstarct true**.

For mor information you can see [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionTabs/)

I had created simple [codepen](http://codepen.io/nirmal25/pen/EKKmxe). Which will help you.

So in **templates/index.html**

```
<ion-nav-bar class="bar-positive">
  <ion-nav-back-button>
  </ion-nav-back-button>
</ion-nav-bar>

<ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
```

**templates/login.html**

```
<ion-view view-title="Login" name="login-view">
<ion-content class="padding">
  <div class="list list-inset" >
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="text" placeholder="Username" ng-model="data.username">
      </label>
      <label class="item item-input">
          <input type="password" placeholder="Password" ng-model="data.password">
      </label>
  </div>
  <button class="button button-block button-calm" ng-click="Login()">Login</button>
</ion-content>
</ion-view>
```

**templates/tabs.html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-positive">

    <ion-tab title="Login" icon="ion-home" ui-sref="tabs.login">
      <ion-nav-view name="login-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>

    <ion-tab title="Signup" icon="ion-ios-information" ui-sref="tabs.signup">
      <ion-nav-view name="signup-tab"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-tab>
  </ion-tabs>
```

> //instead of ui-sref we can use ng-click => $state.go('tabs.signup')
>   too.

and in **app.js**

```
$stateProvider
.state('tabs', {
  url: "/tab",
  abstract: true,
  templateUrl: "templates/tabs.html"
})
.state('tabs.login', {
  url: "/login",
  views: {
    'login-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/login.html",
      controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    }
  }
})
.state('tabs.signup', {
  url: "/signup",
  views: {
    'signup-tab': {
      templateUrl: "templates/signup.html"
    }
  }
})

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/tab/login");
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for your feedback maybe that could help me